# Can a harmonic number be a rational number for non-integer rational argument?

Tags: nt.number-theory, special-functions, gamma-function, rational-points

Define harmonic numbers for a complex argument $z$ as $H_z=\frac{\Gamma'(z+1)}{\Gamma(z+1)}-\Gamma'(1)$.

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $H_n$ are usual harmonic numbers $\sum^n_{k=1} k^{-1}$ . They are obviously rational and are known (Taeisinger 1915) to be non-integers for $n>1$.

*Question:* Is there a non-integer rational $q$ such that $H_q\in\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Historical details: (1) first published proof of this is by **Theisinger** (Monatshefte für Mathematik und Physik 26, 1915, S. 132–134), not 'Taeisinger' (2) this is misspelling is very widespread (e.g., as of 2020-05-16 it is *still* misspelled by the English Wikipedia in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#cite_note-5, while the German version has it right; (3) I'm of course not the first to note (2); (4) Theisinger used Bertrand's postulate, not the more elementary 2-adic reasoning.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is "no". Your function $H_z$ which is the same as $\psi(z+1)+\gamma$, where $\psi$ is the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function), and $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant, takes transcendental values at non-integer rationals. This is a theorem of M. Ram Murty and N. Saradha, ["Transcendental values of the digamma function"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X06002927).

Notice that at rational values the digamma function has an explicit evaluation given by [Gauss's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Gauss.27s_digamma_theorem).